# In a excel formula I need to create a list of names on one sheet based upon criteria/data of another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets, 1st - Is a running operation report that throughout the day is updating personnel and workflow performance, 2nd - is pure data about the personnel and the work demand for the day. I need a excel formula that will search through the list of personnel in "column B" of the data sheet and extract a list of names based upon their availability status in "column A" of the data sheet. There are multiple types of status but the only one I am needing is "Aval". It then needs to write the list of names in a column format to the operations sheet in "column I" making sure there are no spaces or duplicates.

I have tried multiple VLookUps & Index/Match. Here is my last attempt. It pulls the data with no errors but is creating a list of the availability status not the names.

```
{=INDEX(Personnel!$A3:$B150,ROW(Personnel!A3:B150),MATCH("Aval",(Personnel!$A$3:$A$150),0))}
```

I have this formula in "cell I4" of the operations sheet.

Comment: Look For `INDEX` & `AGGREGATE` or `FILTER` Function if you are trying to return multiple records for a lookup value!

Comment: I have tried the INDEX without success. As far as I know the FILTER is only available in Microsoft 365, which I don't have. As for the AGGREGATE, that is a mathematical function, can you elaborate on how I might apply it here?

Comment: for that you need to create a proper screenshot of your database, showing what you have and what you expect, it becomes easier for someone to provide a solution, could you show us

Comment: Or Mock data will be good to go, !

Comment: refer this link, it provides a clear explanation how to perform an `INDEX` & `AGGREGATE` https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to upload screenshots to stackoverflow. The basis though is simple. I have 2 sheets, sheet 1, A3:A150, has availably for work status and B3:B150 has the corresponding employee names, sheet 2 is a jumbled assortment of data but I just need the list to populate to cell I4 and continuing down the column as far as needed to fit all the names.

Comment: Sir I have shared a link in the above comment of yours, you can go through it please it will help you to understand!,

Comment: Thank you for sharing the feedback, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you the link taught me just what I needed.
My final formula is:
`=IF(ROWS($H$3:H3)<=$I$1,INDEX(Personnel!$B$3:$B$150,AGGREGATE(15,3,(Personnel!$A$3:$A$150='Screen Display'!$I$3)/(Personnel!$A$3:$A$150='Screen Display'!$I$3)*(ROW(Personnel!$A$3:$A$150)-ROW(Personnel!$A$2)),ROWS($H$3:H3))),"")`

Comment: Good really appreciate this. Accept your solution as the answer. !